# Reusable Gherkin Steps

Tags: bdd, gherkin, python-behave

I'm doing a little PoC of system tests with python-behave. I wrote a couple of tests, but I wonder how to scale it:

I have a few scenarios I wrote in Gherkin and implemented in python-behave, and I was wondering: In case there are many testers working on the same project, and the testers want to use the same phrases, so that there won't be code duplication in the python-behave files. How could they go about it?

for instance (please ignore the content of the tests as I wasn't giving it much thought)

Tester 1 writes:

```
  Scenario: Simple Google search
    Given a web browser is on the Google page
    When the search phrase "panda" is entered
    Then results for "panda" are shown
```

Somebody implemented each of the steps in the test in python-behave.

Tester 2 writes:

```
  Scenario: Advanced Google search
    Given there is a web-browser on a Google page
    When the search phrase "panda" is written
    Then results for "panda" are presented
    And the related results include "Panda Express"
    But the related results do not include "pandemonium"
```

Notice that the "Given", "When" and "Then" of the two tests are identical in their logic. Is there a simple way for Tester 2 to know that a similar phrases were already written (and implemented)? Is there a way to search in a "phrase bank" or something of that sort in order to avoid code duplication?

Comment: You could document the steps that you have written - showing which files they are implemented in, a description of what the steps do, and make it searchable - check out these [python documentation tools](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DocumentationTools).

This would be the simplest way to do this - whereby getting your colleagues to document their steps and use the documentation will be the hardest part

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem of step proliferation.  I solved it at the point of creation of the step by using Behave Pro.  Behave Pro is a plugin to Jira.  Each ticket I file in Jira has a section, added by Behave Pro, where I specify the requirements for the ticket in Gherkin.

Behave Pro solves the problem sort of like query-completion works on Google.  As I start to type my step, it searches my existing steps.  If it finds one similar to what I've typed, it proposes it.

I think there's a lot more that can be done in a system like Behave Pro.  There is a lot of Natural Language Processing that could help.  But that's for a really large set of Gherkin scenarios.